# How to change Feature Flags and Feature variables based on app version in Optimizely

Tags: android, optimizely

I have recently started using Optimizely for managing my features, hence my question might be naive. Apologise in advance!

I saw we can configure our feature and its respective variables on the Optimizely dashboard but how we can change the feature variables for different App versions. Let us consider an example - I am making a shopping cart feature in the e-commerce app and I created discount percentage a feature variable under the shopping cart feature. So the use case is, for app version 1.0 discount percentage will be 20 % and for app version 1.1 it will be 30 %.
I saw we can create a feature test and change the value for different variations.

**Q1:** Is this the correct understanding or is there any other good solutions for this?

Some other questions I want to clarify as well

**Q2:** Every time we request a feature flag or feature variables value from OptimizelyClient (Android-SDK) Does it call the server to fetch the value or is there any caching mechanism underneath?

**Q3:** Can we put some notifier on the OptimizelyClient (Android-SDK) that can notify the app when value changes occur on the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have probably solved the issue by now but I wanted to pop info in here anyway.

Q1 - You are trying to bundle two tests together, the people using the app version 1.0 could never be bundled into version 1.1. You should set this up as follows
Test 1. App version 1.0 - Variation 1 20% | Variation 2 30%
Test 2. App version 1.1 - Variation 1 20% | Variation 2 30%

There are some issues with data that you could encounter if you go with your original idea, hence why Optimizely does not allow you to change the audience per variation. You could then compare the two app versions to see why version gives the best sign up based on the discount.

Q2 - The datafile is hosted locally within the SDK, so there is no blocking call out to Optimizely, this means that the SDK has the most up to date JSON file with all the information it needs to bundle users into experiments. How often you update this file is up to you. This is a key feature of the Optimizely SDK.

Q3 - You can configure the datafile to be updated at a time your require, for apps the most common is upon start up. In regards to whether you can update as soon as a change has been made. This is a conversation around optimisation and experience. Does the user need to have a different experience halfway through their usage of the app or do can they wait? I lean towards wait till next boot up. Nethertheless, there is a webhook that I would assume you could use if you really wanted to push a change as soon as you have flipped the flag on.